# Properties of Exponential Distribution

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-distribution

I am confused with the pdf of the exponential distribution,

Some of the times, the pdf is shown as :

$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\ x \ge 0$

while sometimes it is shown as

$f(x)=e^{-\lambda x},\ x \ge 0$

Are there any differences between them?

Edit:

$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $P(X<x)$

$f(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ for $P(X>x)$

Further question:

What about 
$1-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ ? Is this the cdf for $P(X<x)$ or $P(X>x)$?

Comment: The latter cannot be a PDF, it doesn't integrate to $1$. The first one is correct. The latter one could be $e^{-x}$, which is the first one for $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: so is the second one = P(X>x) ?

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, the second is $P(X > x)$  for an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: You can check your question by yourself: The connection between the pdf and cdf is $F'(x)=f(x)$ when $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ and for continuous distributions you have $P(X<x)=P(X\leq x)$. Remember, that a cdf satisfies $F(x\to \infty)=1$ and $F(x\to -\infty)=0$.

Comment: self-check: so $1-\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ is neither the cdf of P(X<x) nor P(X>x). But $1-e^{-\lambda x}$ is the cdf of P(X>x)